# Why won't java output my last method

Tags: java, loops, nested, nested-loops

file:///C:/Users/Chris/Downloads/lab04_guessinggame%20(6).pdf
   *The code won't output the last method

```
import java.util.*;

public class GuessingGame{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        int x=getRandomNumber();
        int y=getGuessFromUser(x);
        int v=getGuessFromUser(x);
    }

    public static int getRandomNumber(){
        return (int)(Math.random()*26);
    }

    public static int getGuessFromUser(int x){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int y;
        int v=0;
        do{
            System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 25: ");
            y=keyboard.nextInt();
            v++;
        } while(y<=0||y>25 || v<5);
        return y;
    }

    public static void main(int x, int y, int v){
        do{
            if(x>y)
                System.out.println("TOO LOW");
            if(x<y)
                System.out.println("TOO HIGH");
            if(x==y)
                System.out.print("YOU ARE CORRECT! IT TOOK YOU " + v + " GUESSES!");
        }while(v<5);
    }
}
```

> The main method won't output

Comment: What do you mean by `The main method won't output`? You have 2 main methods...

Comment: how you are running it?? passing the parameters?

Comment: WHY do you have two main methods ?

Comment: If you never update `v` in your while loop you obtain an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class GuessingGame{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        int x=getRandomNumber();
        int y=getGuessFromUser(x);
        int v=getGuessFromUser(x);
        output(x,y,v);
    }

    public static int getRandomNumber(){
        return (int)(Math.random()*26);
    }

    public static int getGuessFromUser(int x){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int y;
        int v=0;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 25: ");
            y=keyboard.nextInt();
            v++;
        } while(y<=0||y>25 || v<5);
        return y;
    }

    public static void output(int x, int y, int v){
        do {
            if (x>y)
                System.out.println("TOO LOW");
            if (x<y)
                System.out.println("TOO HIGH");
            if (x==y)
                System.out.print("YOU ARE CORRECT! IT TOOK YOU " + v + " GUESSES!");
        } while (v<5);
    }
}
```

As people have said in the comments, you can't have 2 main methods so you have to rename the last one and then call it somewhere. That being said, I just modified your code, but you might want to think some more about how it is structured.

Comment: Well, I disagree. You can have 2 main methods if you have 2 different declarations. In his case, his another main method clearly takes 3 `int` variables. so there is no issue. His code is working fine, at least on my system. He is confused with the another main method, and as you are calling `output()` method, he just has to call, `main(x,y,v)`.

Comment: Did you walk through his code, the logic is flawed.

Comment: @CodeWhisperer I know his logic is wrong, I was just commenting on running state of the code. He clearly said " it doesn't print" that is wrong.

Comment: okay maybe i should've said you 'shouldn't' have 2 main methods

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what are you trying to achieve by this code but regarding

> The main method won't output

There are 2 problem in your code as far as I can see

1. You dint call the `main(int,int,int)`.
2. In `main(int,int,int)` you have a loop which is infinite because `V` never changed.

So the code would be

```
import java.util.*;

public class GuessingGame{
public static void main( String[] args ){
int x=getRandomNumber();
int y=getGuessFromUser(x);
int v=getGuessFromUser(x);
main(x, y,v);
}


public static int getRandomNumber(){
return (int)(Math.random()*26);
}
public static int getGuessFromUser(int x){
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int y;
int v=0;
do{
System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 25: ");
y=keyboard.nextInt();
v++;
}while(y<=0||y>25 || v<5);
return y;
}
public static void main(int x, int y, int v){
do{
if(x>y)
System.out.println("TOO LOW");
if(x<y)
System.out.println("TOO HIGH");
if(x==y)
System.out.print("YOU ARE CORRECT! IT TOOK YOU " + v + " GUESSES!");
}while(v++<5);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be changed:

```
public static void main(int x, int y, int v){
do{
if(x>y)
System.out.println("TOO LOW");
if(x<y)
System.out.println("TOO HIGH");
if(x==y)
System.out.print("YOU ARE CORRECT! IT TOOK YOU " + v + " GUESSES!");
}while(v<5);
}
```

to:

```
public static void checkGuess(int randomNumber, int tries){
    do{
        int guess = getGuessFromUser(randomNumber);
        tries++;

        if(randomNumber > guess) System.out.println("TOO LOW");

        if(randomNumber < guess) System.out.println("TOO HIGH");

        if(randomNumber == guess) 
        System.out.print("YOU ARE CORRECT! IT TOOK YOU " + tries + " GUESSES!");
    }while(tries < 5);
}
```

Changes to main:

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    int x=getRandomNumber();
    int v = 0;
    checkGuess(x, v);
}
```

Changes to getGuessFromUser:

```
public static int getGuessFromUser(int x){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int y;

    do{
        System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and " + x + ": ");
        y=keyboard.nextInt();

    }while(y <= 0 || y > x);

    return y;
}
```

You have many logical and syntax issues in the code. I recommend going step by step in your code and thinking through what it does. Also don't forget to double check on scope of variables.